# Apache and mod_wsgi WSGIDaemonProcess config error

Tags: django, apache, permissions, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having a lot of difficulty with apache(Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04)) and mod_wsgi and my django site. My configuration has been working for a long time, then I'm not sure what I did (possibly because I moved the virtualenv, and didn't reflect this accurately in the config, or possibly just a server upgrade, I'm not sure), but now I get errors like

```
#/var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Dec 22 08:47:04.693620 2014] [:info] [pid 21082:tid 139779033159552] mod_wsgi (pid=21082): Starting process 'mysite.com' with uid=999, gid=999 and threads=4.
[Mon Dec 22 08:47:04.693744 2014] [:alert] [pid 21084:tid 139779033159552] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=21084): Unable to change working directory to '/home/djangoUser'.
[Mon Dec 22 08:47:04.693769 2014] [:alert] [pid 21084:tid 139779033159552] mod_wsgi (pid=21084): Failure to configure the daemon process correctly and process left in unspecified state. Restarting daemon process after delay.
```

and

```
#/srv/apache/log/mysite_error.log
[Mon Dec 22 08:49:31.295810 2014] [core:error] [pid 13999:tid 139778670376704] [client 1.169.91.80:2836] Script timed out before returning headers: mysite.com_wsgi.py
```

I tried reinstalling and re-enabling `mod_wsgi`:

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi
a2enmod wsgi
service apache2 restart
```

and this did not help.

My wsgi file for django looks like:

```
#/srv/apache/mysite.com_wsgi.py  (perms are www-data.www-data 644 on file, 755 dir above)
#!/usr/bin/env python

settings_module = "settings"
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = settings_module

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and my apache conf looks like:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf:

<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    ServerName  www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com


    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/apache/mysite.com_wsgi.py

    # Log file locations
    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog  /srv/apache/log/mysite.com_error.log
    CustomLog /srv/apache/log/mysite.com_access.log combined


    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com processes=4 threads=4 display-name=%{GROUP}  user=djangoUser group=djangoUser python-path=/srv/mysite:/srv/mysite/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup: mysite.com



    <Directory "/srv/apache">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>     


   <Directory "/srv/www/mysite.com/media">
     Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/srv/www/mysite.com/static">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

**Some dir structure notes:**

The django site files are at `/srv/mysite` which is djangoUser.djangoUser 755 (and all files/dirs below are owned by djangoUser too). The virtual env is at `/srv/mysite/venv` and again all owned by djangoUser with same perms pip install gave them. Other files inside `/srv/mysite/` are also owned by djangoUser with dir 500, files 400.

The wsgi file is at `/srv/apache` and it and the apache dir are www-data.www-data with the wsgi file 644 and dir above 755.

The static files are at `/srv/www/mysite.com/static` with everything owned by www-data, and dir .....I can actually access say the favico or robots file without problem...www.mysite.com/favicon.ico shows it without error.

Has anyone got any ideas what the problem could be? I thought at first it must be permissions, but I cannot see any issues.

Finally /etc/passwd shows the djangoUser as

```
djangoUser:x:999:999::/home/djangoUser:/bin/false
```

Comment: Does `/home/djangoUser` exist?

Comment: No, but it never has, and it worked previously whilst spitting out that message...I guess it's worth a try creating it though

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can't quite believe it, but that fixed it. I'd just ignored that part of the message as I've been seeing it for months and months under normal operation...why on earth it would become critical in the last few weeks I do not understand. Thanks though!